# Use of derivators to the theory of motives?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homotopy-theory, motives, triangulated-categories

This is a rather imprecise question but i think this could become a interesting pool of ideas and comments.

The theory of motives has evolved to a complex field of research the moment Voevodsky (and others) have introduced the triangulated categories and concepts of homotopy theory to the field. The/one motivation behind (stable) derivators is to enable a functorial cone construction. This is a problem arising in the theory of triangulated categories.

What improvements in the theory of motives could be derived from the theory of derivators?

Noticing that both concepts where introduced by late Grothendieck made me think if maybe there originally was a conceptual link between these topics in the first place, when he came up with the derivators.

Comment: In the motivic world, model categories and infinity-categories are used as refinements of triangulated categories.  These are "stronger" refinements than derivators (in some precise sense), so I doubt that the theory of derivators can offer any improvements to the theory of motives.

Comment: However, a beautiful idea of Ayoub is to modify the definition of derivator, replacing the 2-category of diagrams by the 2-category of diagrams of _schemes_ over some base, and imposing various axioms.  The resulting notion, which he calls an _algebraic derivator_, essentially captures the whole formalism of six functors.  I am not sure, but I believe that Grothendieck probably did not have anything like this in mind when he wrote Pursuing Stacks or Les Derivateurs (and I will be very happy if an expert could confirm).

Comment: I would like to express my own understanding of Adeel's answer. So, when treating motives over a base one considers certain triangulated motivic categories over each base scheme and also several types of connecting functors between these categories. The motivic categories are equipped with canonical models, and some of the connecting functors possess canonical lifts to models; yet some of the types of these functors do not seem to possess canonical lifts of this sort. I would really like to know whether algebraic derivators solve this problem!

Comment: Thanks so far, Adeel. I had no idea of algebraic Derivators. I will have a look on these

Comment: Two comments on algebraic derivators: 1) the work of Ayoub on the Betti realisation and Ayoub and Cisinski-Deglise on the l-adic realisation shows that the classical theories of systems of coefficients (derived categories of topological sheaves for algebraic varieties over \mathbb{C} and Ekedahl's derived categories of l-adic sheaves) form algebraic derivators and 2) the language of algebraic derivators is useful to express various subtle geometric situations: cohomological descent, stratifications (see Ayoub-Zucker), nearby cycles functor.

Comment: [This is unrelated but wanted to point out that, contrary to Adeel's claim, one can recover a (presentable) stable infty-category from its associated derivator. (see http://www.sciencedirect.com.turing.library.northwestern.edu/science/article/pii/S0022404909000425?via%3Dihub)]

Comment: @DylanWilson The link does not work outside of Northwestern.

Comment: What Dylan meant was this https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jpaa.2009.02.014, which is _Plongement de certaines théories homotopiques de Quillen dans les dérivateurs_,  by Olivier Renaudin

Comment: @DylanWilson: Can you recover the ∞-category of left adjoint functors between two presentable stable ∞-categories from the corresponding category of morphisms of their associated derivators?  Can you compute the pullback of a diagram of presentable stable ∞-categories if you are given the associated diagram of derivators?  (The latter example actually arose in my work in a nonabstract context.)

Comment: I dunno- I've never used derivators for anything myself, I just happen to know that fun fact. Maybe you should ask a separate MO question about it?

Comment: @DylanWilson: I am pretty sure the answer is no.  This was meant to be a comment on your reply to Adeel's remark that ∞-categories are "stronger" refinements than derivators (they indeed are).